# Have any other way in php to stop return undefined value for json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am sent many dynamic post ids from a page and a php server side page(server.php) make a query with those id to find out **newly added data** in mysql.

If it *not found* any **newly added data** in mysql, it's return a `undefined` value. So I added this `if (msg.id !== undefined && msg.detail !== undefined && msg.name !== undefined) { //do here }` to hide undefined.

But after added the above line, my script hide `undefined` value well but return only for 1st CID's newly added value.

That means If CID sent ids(100, 101, 102, 103 ect.) to php, It's return only 100 id's newly added value and append it.

So without use above method, Have any others way to php server side to remove undefined values?

**N.B.** Without above line its returned all CID's value well but return also `undefined` value a time interval if no newly added  data found, So I need to stop return `undefined`.

my javascript:

```
var CID = []; // Get all dynamic ids of posts (works well)
$('div[data-post-id]').each(function(i){
CID[i] = $(this).data('post-id');
});

function addrep(type, msg){
CID.forEach(function(id){
if (msg.id !== undefined && msg.detail !== undefined && msg.name !== undefined) {
    $("#newreply"+id).append("<div class='"+ type +""+ msg.id +"'><ul><div class='newkochi'>"+ msg.name +"</div><div class='cdomment_text'>"+ msg.detail +"</ul></div>");
}
});
}

function waitForRep(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "server.php",
        cache: false,
        data: {CID : CID},
        timeout:15000, 
        success: function(data){ 
            addrep("postreply", data);
            setTimeout(waitForRep, 15000 );
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            setTimeout(waitForRep, 15000); }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    waitForRep();
});
```

server.php

```
while (true) {
    if($_GET['CID']){  //cid got all dynamic post id as: 1,2,3,4 etc.
      foreach($_GET['CID'] as $key => $value){

        $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-15 second'));
        $res = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM reply WHERE qazi_id=".$_GET['tutid']."  AND date >= '$datetime' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
    $data = array();
        while($rows =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){

          $data[]=$rows;

          $data['id'] = $rows['id']; 
          $data['qazi_id'] = $rows['qazi_id'];
          $data['username'] = $rows['username'];
          $data['description'] = $rows['description'];
          $data['date'] = $rows['date'];
          //etc. all
             $id = $rows['id'];
             $qazi_id = $rows['qazi_id'];
             $username = $rows['username'];
             $description = $rows['description'];
             //etc. all
          } //while close
      } //foreach close

          $name .='<p class="name">'.$username.' Says:</p>';
          $detail .=''.$description.'';

          $data['name'] = $name;
          $data['detail'] = $detail;
          // do others something more like as above

           if (!empty($data)) {
              echo json_encode($data);
              flush();
              exit(0);
           }

    } //request close
    sleep(5);
} //while close
```

Comment: it seems that in server.php your $data contains only one row.

Comment: If my server.php $data contains only one row then why its get and return all new value well without added above JS line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting your values

```
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
      $data[] = $rows;
}
```

That's all you should need to do to populate `$data`. `$data[]=$rows;` is telling PHP to append `$rows` to the array `$data`. If you need to change data, edit `$rows` before you do the append.

Comment: Don't do the `$data['id'] = $rows['id'];` lines because you're overwriting all your data

Comment: I solved this problem another a way but thank you so much for this `overwriting` advice